# How to turn UL into an inline list of elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a bootstrap class that would turn this `<ul>` into an inline list:

```
Click one of: <ul class="inline"><li>alpha</li><li>beta</li></ul>
```

It renders to:

```
Click one of: 
  alpha beta
```

I'm expecting:

```
Click one of: alpha beta
```

A workaround is:

```
<ul class="inline" style="display:inline-block"><li>alpha</li><li>beta</li></ul>
```

However, I'm looking for a bootstrap class, to avoid HTML `style` attribute.

Comment: <ul class="inline"><li>Click one of:</li><li>alpha</li><li>beta</li></ul> :P

Comment: Bootstrap is an open-source framework. So you can create a new selector class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add class as `btn-group-vertical` to your html, like

```
Click one of: <ul class="btn-group-vertical inline"><li>alpha</li><li>beta</li></ul>
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4821/)